# What is the equivalent of $array[] = $value in a laravel collection

Tags: laravel, collections

Let's say I have this collection:

```
$collection = collect(['cars'=>[
[['id'=>'1'], ['brand'=>'ford'],['color'=>'green']],
[['id'=>'2'], ['brand'=>'audi'],['color'=>'yellow']],
[['id'=>'3'], ['brand'=>'bmw'],['color'=>'grey']],
[['id'=>'4'], ['brand'=>'honda'],['color'=>'black']]
]]);
```

this collection is used in a recursive func. In every cycle I wan't to perform something like this:

```
$collection->vehicles[] = $brand;
```

the result could be:

```
'cars'=>[
[['id'=>'1'], ['brand'=>'ford'],['color'=>'green']],
[['id'=>'2'], ['brand'=>'audi'],['color'=>'yellow']],
[['id'=>'3'], ['brand'=>'bmw'],['color'=>'grey']],
[['id'=>'4'], ['brand'=>'honda'],['color'=>'black']],
'vehicles'=>['0'=>'ford', '1'=>'audi', '2'=>'bmw', '3'=>'honda']]
```

This is actually an example. What I am looking here for is the equivalent of `$arr[] = $var`. So every time I add a value it automatically adds and indexes it. There are other stuff for that like append, push and put but I could't find the equivalent to this. Is there an equivalent or alternative?

----------- Edited for providing more details ---------------

I would to keep it simple but I think I need to give more details. I have a recursive function that creates a hierarchic collection of categories. While creating this collection I want to create an extra property that holds all items in an (single dimensional flat) array. So I can use it later (like $collection->flat) and don't need to loop the whole collection to flatten it.

```
public static function toHierarchic($items, $parent_id=0, $newItems=null){
    if($newItems===null){ // create a collection for the begining
        $newItems = collect( $items->whereLoose('parent_id', $parent_id) );
    }
    foreach ($newItems as $itemKey => $newItem) {
        $newItem->flat[] = [$newItem-id=>$newItem->title];

        $newItem->children = $children;
        self::toHierarchicObject($items, $newItem->id, $newItem->children);
    }
    return $newItems;
}
```

everything works fine here except `$newItem->flat[] = [$newItem-id=>$newItem->title];` this is the part I asked the question. In each cyle or the recursion I want to add the current name/id to $collection->flat property.

Comment: Can't you just use `$collection->push()`?

Comment: not exactly, push() doesn't create new index on each input.

Comment: Well, than how about `$collection->put($key, $value)`?

Comment: this doesn't do it either. it overwrites itself and returns only one key.

Comment: What overwrites itself? Using `put()` doesn't empty out the entire collection. I think I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Let me phrase it differently: I think you might be doing to much. I'll write an answer.

Comment: This way should work: `$brands[] = 'Opel';
$brands[] = 'Mercedes';
$collection->put('vehicles', $brands);`

Comment: I would keep the question simple but I will edit and give more details.

Comment: @PawelMysior with overwrites itself I meant that at the end of the loop I juts get the last added value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your collection of cars:

```
$collection = collect([
    ['brand' => 'ford', 'color' => 'green'],
    ['brand' => 'audi', 'color' => 'yellow'],
    ['brand' => 'bmw', 'color' => 'grey'],
    ['brand' => 'honda', 'color' => 'black']
]);
```

You can list the brands by like that:

```
$brands = $collection->pluck('brand');
```

Say you want to add a car:

```
$collection->push(['brand' => 'audi', 'color' => 'black']);
```

If you have multiple cars with the same brand in your collection and only want to display a list of brands without duplicates, then do it like this:

```
$uniqueBrands = $collection->unique('brand')->pluck('brand');
```

Comment: the collection is actually nested thats why I can't use that.

Comment: I'm just saying, maybe you need to change your collection. If that's possible of course.